# Grails 3.1.10 Can't find views

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a 'JacketController' with a method show() trying to render a model to the view worklist.gsp

> ```
>   def show() {
>         LOG.debug("JacketController:show()")
>         render(view:"worklist", model:PatientSearchResult.list()) as HTML
>     }
> ```

But every time I call the action from the browser I get the error:

> ```
> [Could not resolve view with name '/jacket/worklist' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'] with root cause  StandardWrapperValve.java 250 javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name /jacket/worklist' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'...
> ```

I would think it's telling me worklist.gsp doesn't exist or is in the wrong place but worklist.gsp is in the grails-app/views/jacket directory.

My url mapping looks as follows:

```
        "/jacket" {
        controller = { 'jacket' }
        action = { GET: 'show' }
    }
```

I don't know if I'm missing a plugin or what but my build.gradle is here:(forgive the formatting)

> ```
> buildscript {
> ext {
>     grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
> }
> repositories {
>     mavenLocal()
>     maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
> }
> dependencies {
>     classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
>     classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.10"
>     classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.0.12"
>     classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.11.2"
>  }} configurations.all {
> resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
>     if (details.requested.name == 'log4j') {
>         details.useTarget "org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.5"
>     }
>     if (details.requested.name == 'commons-logging') {
>         details.useTarget "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5"
>     }
>
> } }
> ```
>
> version "0.1" group "viops"
>
> apply plugin:"eclipse" apply plugin:"idea" apply plugin:"war" apply
>   plugin:"org.grails.grails-web" apply
>   plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json" apply
>   plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp" apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
>
> ext {
>       grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
>       gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion }
>
> repositories {
>       mavenLocal()
>       maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" } }
>
> dependencyManagement {
>       imports {
>           mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
>       }
>       applyMavenExclusions false }
>
> dependencies {
>       //This top section pulls out Grails Logback logging solution and
>       //replaces it with log4j2
>       // added the new way using Log4j2, yes, spring makes it easy
>       compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2"
>
> ```
> // changed spring-boot-autoconfigure so that it would not
> // pull in the logback binding/implementation
> compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure') {
>     exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
> }
> compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'){
>     exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
> }
>
>
> // and finally, added the log4j2 binding/implementation
> compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.5"
> compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.5"
>
> compile "org.grails:grails-core"
> provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
> compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
> compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
> compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs"
> compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
> compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
> compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource"
> compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
> compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-async"
> compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
> compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
> compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
> compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
> compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
> compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json"
> console "org.grails:grails-console"
> profile "org.grails.profiles:rest-api"
> runtime "com.h2database:h2"
> testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
> testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
> testCompile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client"
> testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
> testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18" }
> ```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try to include the web profile dependency

Comment: +quindimildev Thank you. What I did was created a new project with the web profile and compared the resulting build files. I brought over the dependencies that were missing in the REST profile and commented out a couple that might have conflicted.  Works now.

Comment: you are welcome, answer yourself and mark as solved ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quindimildev posted the answer in the comment.

I should have created an app with the web profile to begin with. So, I created a new project with the web profile and compared the resulting build files with the existing app.

I brought over the dependencies that were missing in the REST profile and commented out a couple that might have conflicted.

Answer (score 0):

You miss a dependency to make gsp work correctly:

```
        compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
```